# 0 concat displays first and last name but only first name is saved to mysql database

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $databasename = "test";

  $conn = new mysqli($servername , $username , $password, $databasename);
  $name = $_POST["firstname"];
  $last = $_POST["lastname"];
   $statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO user(firstname ,lastname) VALUES(?,?)");
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement ,"si", $name,$last);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

where is the problem in above php script that it save the first name in database while cannot save the lastname.

Comment: And your `form` is where?

Comment: What does "0 concat" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of this line,

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement ,"si", $name,$last);
                                     ^ see here
```

It should be,

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement ,"ss", $name,$last);
```